# Embedding an excel file on a website for further editing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, javascript, import, wordpress, embedded

I have been provided with an excel sheet that has a tonne of calculations on it (an economics model) and have been asked to place it online.

It would take days to debunk and code into a webpage, so was looking at other alternatives?

The economics model has inputs and outputs with calculation behind it, essentially a calculator, so are there any plugins/ options that allow me to embed the sheet onto a web page so it can be further edited (for the user inputs)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Google Sheets? It's easy enough to upload and provision access to it.

[Working with Office Files in Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055139?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

There are also commercial services that allow you to publish/embed Excel spreadsheet models (even complex ones) to your website.  I'm most familiar with [AnalysisPlace.com](http://analysisplace.com), but I know there are others.  They optionally enable additional capabilities, such as downloadable output reports, collection of data entered, usage monitoring, and collaboration.  They also provide VBA-like control via JavaScript.